# How do I ssh to a file socket

Tags: ssh

I've created an SSH tunnel to a remote machine, with the local entry being a file socket, using -L /tmp/my.socket:127.0.0.1:22

Now how do I use ssh to connect to that file socket instead of a regular network host?

I'm doing this because I need to have many concurrent connections, each specific to a particular user, and I don't want other users to accidentally/intentionally connect to other users sockets.  I have to connect this way, because I need to use a specific user to connect to the machine remotely, but can then connect as a non-privileged user, on localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using netcat as a `ProxyCommand` might work:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -U /tmp/my.socket' some-host
```

Comment: Yes, the above works with <username>@localhost however it obviously complains that my known_hosts entry for localhost doesn't match.  Any ideas how to get it to ignore that?

Comment: But testing the above <username>@<actual host> seems to work too (connecting via the socket), without complaining about the known_host issue, so this is defo a winner

Comment: @sibaz you can copy the actual host's key in `known_hosts` and add an entry for `localhost` with it. Hosts can have multiple keys in `known_hosts`.

Comment: problem with that is where you're proxying, localhost, isn't the local machine, so in the case I mentioned updating known_hosts to identify some other box, as localhost, is likely to cause other problems.  Hence I wanted a way to have it ignore that.  As mentioned, I found that even when connecting to a local socket, specifying username@<host>, will identify that socket (as far as known_hosts is concerned) as being <host>, which is a winner to my problem.